# I get this error when I import a table in phpmyadmin. How do I solve it?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

> Warning: #3719 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.

Comment: that's not an error but a warning and should not block your import.

Comment: Not an error and as the warning says, change your character set to UTF8MB4

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with this error, when you import your table in PHPMyAdmin, edit the query and add this `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4` at the end of your query, it worked for me! (: